# cannot boot into slitaz linux

Tags: slitaz

I have just installed "slitaz.4.0-base" linux using the guidelines stated at http://doc.slitaz.org/en:handbook:installation#manual-by-hand-installation

But the OS isn't booting. The grub loader is displayed but no action is performed. The OS isn't getting booted. It again displays the same loader.

Comment: You will not get too much attention to your problem if you do not provide more information from the beginning. What can you see? Do you have kernel logs? What does the error say? What's actually displayed by the grub loader?

Comment: I got the answer. the kernel wasn't defined properly.